# Find superscript text in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, microsoft-office-2016, word-processing

I want to use Find and Replace to locate all instances of superscript text throughout a Word 2016 document.

I had a look at Microsoft Technet's [search string guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff956107.aspx) but couldn't find one for superscript text.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the "Advanced Find" in word.

On the Home tab, click on the Find Dropdown on the right hand side and click "Advanced Find"

[image]

You don't need to enter any text here as we are looking for a specific format, instead, click on "Format" at the bottom left, then "Font..."

[image]

check the "Superscript" box and press OK

[image]

then Press Find!

Comment: Fantastic, this is a really clear and useful answer! Thanks again.